# How to remove inline styling in @Html.ValidationSummary

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have used @Html.ValidationSummary(false) which add UL, LI. In LI there is a style applied that is display none.

li style="display:none"

Now we are going to add a header Content-Security-Policy and do not want to allow unsafe-inline style. So how can style be replaced with class in validation list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am now stuck on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the ValidationSummary to return and empty string (or anything you need) instead of an LI with an inline style...

```
    using System.Web.Mvc.Html;

    namespace System.Web.Mvc
    {
    public static class HtmlExtensions
    {
        public static IHtmlString CustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors, string message, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            var validationSummary = htmlHelper.ValidationSummary(excludePropertyErrors, message, htmlAttributes) ?? new MvcHtmlString("");
            var validationSummaryHtmlString = new HtmlString(validationSummary.ToHtmlString().Replace(" style=\"display:none\"", ""));
            return validationSummaryHtmlString;
        }
        public static IHtmlString CustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string message, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return CustomValidationSummary(htmlHelper, false, message, htmlAttributes);
        }
        public static IHtmlString CustomValidationSummary(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool excludePropertyErrors)
        {
            return CustomValidationSummary(htmlHelper, excludePropertyErrors, null, null);
        }
    }
    }
```

Then use your new validationSummary in your view:

```
@Html.Raw(@Html.CustomValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" }).ToString())
```

You can just style out the ugliness of the empty list item with something like:

```
    .validation-summary-valid li:empty{
        display: none;
    }
```